# When does MySQL ORDER BY RAND() function order?

Tags: mysql, performance, random

I've read about the ORDER BY RAND() and its performance problems -- do these only apply to queries that return large datasets?  For example, if I have a table with 100,000 rows and return a dataset with 10 records using a WHERE clause and then use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1, will this ORDER BY RAND() be applied AFTER my table has been filtered down to records matching the WHERE clause, and thus have negligible performance issues?

Comment: Virtually anything can go quickly when only working with small datasets, but conceptually a LIMIT applies after an ORDER BY clause. So it depends on the query optimizer. Why not just try it on a test DB?

Comment: See my experiment below -- the ORDER BY RAND() is applied to the subset of records returned by the WHERE clause -- for a recordset that returns 143 records, limiting to a random record took a negligible additional amount of time, while applying it to the entire table with no where clause took significantly more time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, it will apply the ORDER BY after reducing the number of rows with WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING.  But it will apply ORDER BY before LIMIT.

So if you filter the number of rows down sufficiently, then yes, the ORDER BY RAND() may achieve what you want without a great performance impact.  There's a legitimate benefit to code that is simple and easily readable.

The trouble comes when you *think* your query should reduce the rows to something small, but over time as your data grows, the number of rows it needs to sort becomes large again.  Since your query then does LIMIT 10 on the sorted result hides the fact that you're performing ORDER BY RAND() on 500k rows.  You just see performance mysteriously getting worse.

I have written about alternative methods for picking a random row in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/), or in other answers here on Stack Overflow:

- [Selecting random rows with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql/6542113#6542113)
- [randomizing large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558665/randomizing-large-dataset/3558919#3558919)
- [quick selection of a random row from a large table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql/213242#213242)

Comment: Two other posters contradicted your answer and said it always generates a random number for all rows in the table regardless of the WHERE clause; based on my own test, your answer was the right answer.  Thanks!  In my case, I need a random row from a small subset of a database table.

Comment: Bill, if you read this, I read about your 2 query technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558665/randomizing-large-dataset/3558919#3558919 and in my case I need to use a query with multiple joins, etc.  Does this technique work in that case, too?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how many rows you select. If you `ORDER BY RAND()` a random number is calculated for every single row in the table. This is because it must calculate the random value for every row in order to know which row generated the largest value. So if you have a table with 100,000 rows and then call `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` You are telling MySQL to generate a random number for 100,000 rows, sort them by that number, and then give you the first one.

It is much much faster to:

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Table`
2. Generate random number between 0 and result of above query minus 1 in your scripting/programming language.
3. SELECT * FROM `Table` LIMIT random_number_here,1

Comment: We should not use ```LIMIT randnumber,1;``` Instead, we should using ```WHERE id>randnumber LIMIT 1;``` Offset is inefficient. Might as well do RAND().

Comment: If you have gaps in your id range using the id like this would skew the results.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick test, I have to conclude that ORDER BY RAND() is applied only ***after*** the WHERE statement is applied, and not to the whole dataset.

Results from a table with 50,000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` LIMIT 1  (1 total, Query took 0.0007 sec)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE First = 'Hilda' LIMIT 1 (1 total, Query took 0.0010 sec)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE First = 'Hilda' (142 total, Query took 0.0201 sec)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE First = 'Hilda' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 (1 total, Query took 0.0229 sec)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE First = 'Hilda' ORDER BY RAND() (142 total, Query took 0.0236 sec)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 (1 total, Query took 0.4224 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RAND()` value will be calculated for each row, so it's not very efficient for large data sets, the `LIMIT` clause doesn't change that. The usual way to work around this is to compute a random number in advance and then retrieve the row corresponding to it based on some pregenerated indexed column.

Here's one detailed explanation:

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` is about the last to execute, but `LIMIT` is the VERY LAST.

Unfortunately, this means that the DB is going to generate random numbers for all qualifying rows, order them, and then apply the limit.

What you could do is to have the table with a surrogate `id` field, generate a random number, and then use

`SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE id >= your_rand_number`