# Php query lagging server

Tags: php

So i have a rather big query which  searched though 6k members and 3k websites this use to be good on website start up but now the site is getting huge the page which does this query has started to lag just looking for  suggestions on how i could speed it up

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
FROM websites w
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = w.owner
WHERE u.coins >= ? 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1');
$stmt212->execute( array('1') ) ;
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```

The users have "coins" on my website and items they earn coins and then there item gets viewed so what im doing above is  grabbing a user where there coins is more than 1 and who has a item

Comment: are u.username,  w.owner and u.coins all indexed

Comment: ^lol didn't even see that, order by rand is  performance death http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does MySQL ORDER BY RAND() function order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910613/when-does-mysql-order-by-rand-function-order)

Comment: so i just take the ORDER BY RAND out ?

Comment: i removed the ORDER BY RAND and the speed has increased a lot

Comment: no one said simply remove it, because that changes the resutls you get.

Comment: so whats the best thing todo?If i still want a random / different result each time

Comment: @nicholasdavies do you have an id as the primary key? You can create a random id value in php and then pass that to the sql select statement.

Comment: You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function to learn how to optimize ORDER BY RAND() in mysql

Comment: i have a id field / collum but no primary key set i have a id column inside both tables that im selecting from

Answer (score 0):

As stated in most comments, using `RAND()` in a query *can* be a bad thing. I'm presuming both columns are not indexed, this makes it the database driver very difficult.

To keep your database structure and to maintain performance, you can let PHP randomize your indexes for you:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
  SELECT * 
  FROM websites w
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = w.owner
  WHERE u.coins >= ?
');

$stmt->execute(array('1')); // why are you not checking if this succeeds?
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$result = array_rand($result);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do with with two queries instead of one.

> Get the number of records that match your criteria

```
$stmt212count = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        websites w
    INNER JOIN
        users u ON
            u.username = w.owner
            AND u.coins >= :coins
");
$stmt212count->bindValue('coins', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt212count->execute();
$row212count = $stmt212count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

> Pick a random row

```
# random row offset
$offset = rand(0, $row212count-1);
```

> use this statement if you have PDO emulated prepares turn on

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare(sprintf(
    "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            websites w
        INNER JOIN
            users u ON
                u.username = w.owner
                AND u.coins >= :coins
        LIMIT %d,1
    ",
    $offset
);
$stmt212count->bindValue('offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

> use this if you aren't using PDO emulated prepares

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        websites w
    INNER JOIN
        users u ON
            u.username = w.owner
            AND u.coins >= :coins
    LIMIT :offset,1
");
```

> use this for both statements

```
$stmt212count->bindValue('coins', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt212count->execute();
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```